# Why $ \Im \frac{1}{1+e^{-s + i a }}=\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)+\cosh(s)} $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-transform, hyperbolic-functions

Why this $$ \Im \frac{-2}{1+e^{-s + i a }} $$

equals to this expression:

$$\\\  \frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)+\cosh(s)}
$$

I was trying to evaluate the Fourier transform of a hyperbolic function and my textbook and the other sources say this equality holds on. I only got to:

$$ \Im \frac{e^{-ia}}{e^{-ia}+e^{-s}} $$

Well, generally the imaginary part of $e^{-ia}$ is $\sin(a)$, but $e^{-s}$ is real. So I don't understand the $\cosh (s)$ part. I am just so confused.

The fourier tranform has been done on this function:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(\pi x)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a slightly different result. Consider the following calculation.
\begin{align*}
\Im \frac{1}{1+e^{-s+ia}} &= \Im \frac{1}{1+e^{-s}(\cos(a)+i \sin(a))} \\
&=\Im \frac{1}{1+e^{-s}\cos(a) + ie^{-s}\sin(a)} \cdot \frac{1+e^{-s}\cos(a) - ie^{-s}\sin(a)}{1+e^{-s}\cos(a) - ie^{-s}\sin(a)} \\
&= \Im \frac{1+e^{-s}\cos(a) - ie^{-s}\sin(a)}{(1+e^{-s}\cos(a))^2 + (e^{-s}\sin(a))^2} \\
&= \frac{-e^{-s}\sin(a)}{1+2e^{-s}\cos(a)+e^{-2s}\cos(a)^2 + e^{-2s}\sin(a)^2} \\
&= \frac{ -e^{-s}\sin(a)}{1+2e^{-s}\cos(a)+e^{-2s}}\\
&= \frac{ -\sin(a)}{e^{s} +2\cos(a)+e^{-s}}\\
&=\frac{-\sin(a)}{2\left( \frac{e^s+e^{-s}}{2}+\cos(a) \right)} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin(a)}{\cosh(s)+\cos(a)}
\end{align*}

I get a factor of $-1/2$ in front of your suggested result.

---

Your confusion about the expression
$$
\Im \frac{e^{-ia}}{e^{-ia}+e^{-s}}
$$
might arise because you can not see the real and the imaginary parts from this expression, as there is also an $i$ in the denominator of the fraction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed -2 in the first expression :)

Comment: I suppose the result for $s \gt 0$ is the same as for $s \lt 0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true.